# How do I use joi to validate email

Tags: node.js, express, validation, jwt, joi

I have been stuck on how I can validate using joi npm. Please how do I get to render the register and login route for the user to access without using the ejs or html? And also create a protected route

```
const express = require("express");
const Joi = require("joi");
const app = express();


const schema = Joi.object({
email: Joi.string().email().required(),
password: Joi.string().min(4).alphanum().required(),
firstname: Joi.string().alphanum().required(),
lastname: Joi.string().alphanum().required()
});

app.post("/register", async(req,res) => {
try{
    const value = await schema.validateAsync({
        email:req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        lastname: req.body.lastname
    })
} catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
email: Joi.string().email({ tlds: { allow: false } });
```

use this joi validation for email

Comment: But how di i render the register page for  user to register